# How to get dct:subjects for all entities using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am using the following query

```
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
SELECT ?subject WHERE { 
?concept rdfs:label 'Exoskeleton'@en ; 
         ^dct:subject ?subject . 
}  
ORDER BY ?subject
```

This doesn't give me any results. However, the `rdfs:label` exists. (See http://dbpedia.org/page/Exoskeleton.)

On querying with a different label, it works :

```
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
SELECT ?subject WHERE { 
?concept rdfs:label 'Machine learning'@en ; 
         ^dct:subject ?subject . 
}  
ORDER BY ?subject
```

The above query works and gives me the results. (See http://dbpedia.org/page/Machine_learning.)

What do I change, such that the first query works too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devil is in the details:

```
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
SELECT ?concept WHERE { 
  ?concept rdfs:label 'Machine learning'@en. 
}  
ORDER BY ?concept
```

Returns two results:

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Machine_learning
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Machine_learning

While Exoskeleton has no corresponding concept:

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Exoskeleton

Thus your inverse property path finds resources under a http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Machine_learning concept but not under a http://dbpedia.org/resource/Machine_learning or http://dbpedia.org/resource/Exoskeleton pages.

If you drop the inverse modifier,

```
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
SELECT ?subject WHERE { 
?concept rdfs:label 'Exoskeleton'@en ; 
         dct:subject ?subject . 
}  
ORDER BY ?subject
```

[Will return](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX++dct%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E+%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fsubject+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A%3Fconcept+rdfs%3Alabel+%27Exoskeleton%27%40en+%3B+%0D%0A+++++++++dct%3Asubject+%3Fsubject+.+%0D%0A%7D++%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fsubject&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) the categories (`subject`) for the concepts under a given label.

Comment: Hi, If you go to http://dbpedia.org/page/Exoskeleton , you'll find that there are some entries under dct:subject. How do I get those to show up using a sparql query.? Could you please help me out.

Comment: @KaustabhDattaChoudhury updated the answer with the new query. You just need to drop the inverse path modifier `^`.

Comment: Thank you very much.! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `dct:subject` predicate is used between a page and a category it belongs to. So, your second query is giving you results that are in [Category:Machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Machine_learning). But since there is no [Category:Exoskeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Exoskeleton), your first query gives you no results. This also means the two pages you liked to are irrelevant to your queries.

I don't know how to change the first query so that it works, because I don't understand what would "working" entail.

Comment: Hi, If you go to http://dbpedia.org/page/Exoskeleton , you'll find that there are some entries under dct:subject. How do I get those to show up using a sparql query.? Could you please help me out.